# API not getting called in service file Angular 7

Tags: javascript, service, angular7

I am working with a news App. When I try to call API, it is not getting called in service file function. When I try to console it is getting consoled but when I see network tab there is no API called.

Component file:

```
newPostView(postId: { split: (arg0: string) => any[]; }) {
       postId = postId.split("-")[1];
       this.data = {
           postId: postId,
           postType: localStorage.language
       }
       this._newsService.newsCount(this.data);
}
```

Below is my function in the service file.

```
newsCount(data) {
        console.log("post data", data);
        return this.http.put(config.baseApiUrl + 'post-views', data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning from the service file then you should subscribe in component file. So your updated code should look like this.

Component File:

```
newPostView(postId: { split: (arg0: string) => any[]; }) {
        postId = postId.split("-")[1];
        this.data = {
            postId: postId,
            postType: localStorage.language
        }
        this._newsService.newsCount(this.data).subscribe((res:any) =>{

        });
}
```